# Same height images with Bootstrap v4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have images with the same height but different width.
How to show them in a row with the same height and make it responsive.

For example, I want to show 3 images in one row so that each image has the same height.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="float-left">
    <img src="img1.png" class="??">
  </div>
  <div class="float-left">
    <img src="img2.png" class="??">
  </div>
  <div class="float-left">
    <img src="img3.png" class="??">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick a height and width e.g 3 then write `<img src="img.png" height="3" width="3">`

Answer (score 0):

Semi-responsive solution.

Use media queries to have different height for each screen size.

It is not fully responsive and images will not take the full width of the container. But each image has the same height - a fixed height for each screen size.

HTML (HAML):

```
.row.my-list
  .card.d-flex.align-items-stretch.align-self-center
    %img.card-img-top{:src => "img1.png"}/
  .card.d-flex.align-items-stretch.align-self-center
    %img.card-img-top{:src => "img2.png"}/
  .card.d-flex.align-items-stretch.align-self-center
    %img.card-img-top{:src => "img3.png"}/
```

CSS (SASS):

```
.my-list{
  .card{
    border: 0;
  }

  img{
    @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
      height: 40px;
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
      height: 100px;
    }

  }

}
```